# Android - Reading http request

Tags: android, arduino

I'm doing a project with Arduino and Android application. Here's how it goes, send from the application request "a=11&b=22&d=33" (http://192.168.0.17/?a=11&b=22&d=33), arduino read and return "Data_received" and I use it to do something (down is part of code from app). And everything is going well. But I do not know how to do reversed now, I know how to send the request from arduino to server, but I don't know how to receive in android app to get a = 11, b = 22, c = 33. 
Android studio code to receive:

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        if (serverResponse.toString().equals("Data_received")  ){

           Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Data is ok...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else{

            Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Connection is not ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
```

Arduino code which receives request in arduino:

```
boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
boolean currentLineIsGet = true;
int tCount = 0;
char tBuf[64];
int a;
int b;
int d;
char *pch;
while (client.connected()) {
  while (client.available()) {

    char c = client.read();
    if (currentLineIsGet && tCount < 63)
    {
      tBuf[tCount] = c;
      tCount++;
      tBuf[tCount] = 0;
    }


    if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
      while (client.available()) client.read();

      Serial.print (tBuf);
      pch = strtok(tBuf, "?");

      while (pch != NULL) {

        //  http://192.168.0.17/?a=11&b=22&d=33
        if (strncmp(pch, "a=", 2) == 0)  {
          a = atoi(pch + 2);
          Serial.print("a=");
          Serial.println(a, DEC);
        }
        if (strncmp(pch, "b=", 2) == 0)  {
          b = atoi(pch + 2);
          Serial.print("b=");
          Serial.println(b, DEC);
        }
        if (strncmp(pch, "d=", 2) == 0) {
          d = atoi(pch + 2);
          Serial.print("d=");
          Serial.println(d, DEC);
        }
        pch = strtok(NULL, "& ");

      }  //  while (pch != NULL)

      client.stop();
    }

   }
}
```

All code:

public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {

```
     public EditText text__T1mod;
        public EditText text__T2mod; 
        public EditText text__T3mod; 



private TextView Text_Arduino;

private Button SendRequest ;

public int a;
public int b;
 public int c;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);



    SendRequest  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_SendRequest );



    text__T1mod = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TextEdit_T1);
    text__T2mod = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TextEdit_T2);
    text__T3mod = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TextEdit_T3);


    Text_Arduino = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Arduino);


}  //  protected void onCreate  END




public void clik_SendRequest (View view) {

    String RequestString = "";

    if (IpAddres.getText().toString().equals(""))
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter IP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    else {

        if (view == SendRequest )

         //  http://192.168.1.14/?a=11&b=22&d=33
        RequestString = "a=" + text__T1mod.getText().toString() + "&"
                     +  "b=" + text__T2mod.getText().toString() + "&"
                     +  "d=" + text__T3mod.getText().toString() ;

                              // 192.168.1.14                         // 80
        String serverAdress = IpAddres.getText().toString() + ":" + Port.getText().toString() + "?";
        HttpRequestTask requestTask = new HttpRequestTask(serverAdress);
        requestTask.execute(RequestString);

    }  //  else END

} // clik_SendRequest END


private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private String serverAdress;
    private String serverResponse = "";
    private AlertDialog dialog;

    public HttpRequestTask(String serverAdress) {
        this.serverAdress = serverAdress;

        dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("HTTP zahtev za Ip adresu: ")
                .setCancelable(true)
                .create();


    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String val = params[0];

        final String url = "http://" + serverAdress  + val;



        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet();
            getRequest.setURI(new URI(url));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            serverResponse = bufferedReader.readLine();
            inputStream.close();


        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {

            Log.e("", "parse error2: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            serverResponse = e.getMessage();
        } 

        return serverResponse;
    }




    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        /*
                ----- HERE I NEED IF SOMETHING LIKE arrives ----
         if (serverResponse.toString().equals("?a=11&b=22&d=33")  ){

           Toast.makeText(Test.this, "a=" a + "b=" b + "c=" c , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Connection is not ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        */

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Text_Arduino.setText("pleas wait...");
    }


} //  private class HttpRequestTask
```

} //  public class Test  END

Comment: Post your  do in background method.

Comment: 'I know how to send the request from arduino to server, ...' What kind of request exactly? And what kind of server is running on android device?

Comment: You are not showing how your arduino client connects to an android server.

Comment: I have no problem to receives a request, this is a request that I get in app for example is serverResponse = "?a=11&b=22&d=33" . And now I need to extract the value of a, b and c. In this case a is 11, b is 22 and c is 33

Comment: Then why do you post all that code? You only had to tell us: I have a string "?a=11&b=22&d=33" . How do i parse the values out? The rest is irrelevant.

Comment: How to determine the key=value pairs in a query string?

Comment: Use replace() to replace the questionmark by an empty string. than use the split() function to split the string in three parts on the ampersand char. Any further help needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- Poll the server: write a function on the server that returns the results you need. Then setup a timer in android that calls this function every few seconds
- Push messages from the server: use a push service to send your results to the android app. ex: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

To parse your server response string:

```
String serverResponse = "?a=11&b=22&d=33";
String[] args = serverResponse.substring(1).split("&");
String a = args[0].split("=")[1];
String b = args[1].split("=")[1];
String c = args[2].split("=")[1];
```

Comment: thank you user6709464 on fast response, but this will need for lot requests so it would be better to write code that can read requests such as is on Arduino code, to read the value after the "?" and between "&", so that I can get from the request, for example, a=11, b=22 ....  but I don't know how to write code in Java for app...

Comment: Thank you so much, so little code that bothered me a lot :)  I have just one more question, in this statements:  if (serverResponse.toString().equals("?a=11&b=22&d=33"), a=11 and b=22 and d=33 are not always the same value but  "?" is always on start of request, how they can catch only "?" . something such as, for example, if (serverResponse.toString().equals(STARTS WITH "?")....

Comment: String test = serverResponse;
   String FirstLetter=test.substring(0,1);
            if (FirstLetter.equals("?")  )